# Run tasks one after another

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

> Error: cannot convert from system.thread.tasks.task to
>   system.action

```
Task A = Task.Run(() => Filecopy.COPY_F(txtpatterns.Lines, txtsourcepath.Text));

Task B = Task.Run(() => Unzip.Data(Filecopy.zipfilepath));

Task C = Task.Run(() => GIO_LOad.Data(Unzip.GIOlist));


Task t = null;
t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => A
                             .ContinueWith(B)
                             .ContinueWith(C),
                             TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()));
```

I'm trying to run these tasks one by one, because task B will get `List<string>` from task A and task c will get listof string from task B.

Comment: Why even bother with threads if you want them to run sequentially?

Comment: `async/await` means you don't need ContinueWith at all

Comment: @TJWolschon Looks like the intent is to run the first two in a non-UI thread, and the last in a UI thread (although it doesn't succeed in that endeavor).  In that case, there's no need to break up the first two into separate continuations, but the use of tasks and continuations in general would be sensible.